# How to list files with .c and .h in a directory with Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

How do I list the files with `.c` and `.h` files in a directory.
Presently am using `if(m/.\.c$/)` it only giving `.c` files. I need regex for both `.c` and `.h` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perl, you can list all the files with `.c` and `.h` extension from a directory with following code:

```
opendir my $dir, "some/path/" or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = grep{/\.c$|\.h$/}readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;
print "@files";
```

---

**Edit**
If you really want use `if()`, you can do like this:

```
opendir my $dir, "some/path/" or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;
foreach (@files)
{
    if (/.\.[ch]\z/s)
    {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ,i want to use with in if ()

Comment: `/\.c\z|\.h\z/` or `/\.[ch]\z/`, actually

Comment: `/.\.[ch]\z/s` is better since it doesn't match the file named `.c` or `.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Use character class. That is, put `c` and `h` inside the square brackets.

```
if(m/.\.[hc]$/)
```

`[hc]` matches `h` or `c`

Comment: `m/.\.[hc]\z/s`, actually

Comment: @ikegami what's the need for `s` modifier here?

Comment: So `.` matches any char.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of files in a directory, use `glob()` . See `perldoc -f glob` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html

```
my @files = glob( "$path/*.[ch]" );
print "$path : @files\n";
```

If there are spaces in the path or file names, use the bsd_glob from `File::Glob`

```
use File::Glob qw( :bsd_glob );
my @files = glob( "$path/*.[ch]" );
print "$path : @files\n";
```

See `perldoc File::Glob` http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html

`File::Glob` is a standard module and is installed with Perl. For a list of all standard modules, see `perldoc perlmodlib` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html